# Intercept compilation after semantic analysis

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, compilation

I am looking for a way to intercept the compilation process (of a C++ program, in Visual Studio but I am also interested in other tools).

I would like to

**(1) get the results of the semantic analysis in some kind of tree structure**

**(2) insert some new statements automatically and**

**(3) give it back to the compiler to continue its work.**

I would use this to examine and validate how my multithreaded program works by inserting before each statement some code to (a) signal that the line of code was reached (b) wait for a signal (e.g. event) from an external program and (c) execute the actual statement.

Since I would like to insert this code before each statement, I need an automatic method. However, using regexes or some similar simple technique would not take into consideration all rules of the language, e.g. an if statement can contain a single statement without { and } indicating the beginning and end of a code block - in this case, inserting the code before the statement inside if, would completely change the original meaning of the source. Making difference between functions and structs may be difficult, too.

**So, please recommend me some tools / techniques to do this.**

Comment: Don't think Microsoft will document anything like that. A different starting point could be [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch), but it will probably be *a lot* of work.

Comment: @BoPersson: Well, it is exactly the kind of work LLVM was designed to allow for, wasn't it? (OP: [LLVM](http://LLVM.org) is the compiler infrastructure underpinning clang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Microsoft compiler is not open to do such transformations.
Maybe it's better to use the Clang compiler, you can refer to this interesting [article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/07/29/ast-matchers-and-clang-refactoring-tools) to have an idea how to change the tree.